# Custom SQL With PHP for querying custom services

Tags: php, sql, service

Let's assume I have a backend service that holds account data and I want to be able to query it with SQL to get data back, a "Power User" interface for administrative users.

In the past I've worked for a hosting company that used a service that managed accounts on WHM with something exactly like this written in Python, however I never worked on that project and have no idea how it was done.

Are there any existing libraries that could be adapted for this? Or better, something designed specifically for creating a custom SQL?

**For instance:**

```
ACCOUNT CREATE ('username', 'password', 'email') VALUES ('bob_barker', 'some_password', 'bbarker@somesite.com');
```

I just invented that on the fly, but it serves as a valid example. In corollary, are there any libraries designed to format arrays of data like MySQL does over the CLI? (eg, placing the output into an associative array, passing it off, and echoing the returned formatted text?)

Comment: you would have to use [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and [loops](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Comment: I think you will struggle to find something which comes near the syntax which you would actually like (and none that are the same). Besides the fact that if choosing to use type rather than a GUI for "power users" to execute queries it probably better they actually learn SQL as this skill will be portable no?

Comment: @verbumSapienti Why link to the MySQLi functions? They have no bearing on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an [SQL parser](http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser), you can extend with your own keywords. Next you have to compile (or interpret) the Abstract Syntax Tree. That gives you most control over, what users can do to the database.